# Find $a, b \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}=\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, fractions

> Find $a, b \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

My try :

$$\frac{[a,b]+(a,b)}{[a,b] \cdot (a,b)}=\frac{ab-2a-2b}{2ab}.$$

Now what to do?

Comment: What are $(a,b)$ and $[a, b]$ ?

Comment: @PeterPhipps: GCD and LCM, respectively.

Comment: @PeterPhipps Greatest common divisor and Least common multiple

Comment: There seem to be quite a few solutions, eg 5,20; 9,24; 6,12; 8,8; 8,12; 12,15.

Comment: How'd you get $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} +\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}=\frac{[a,b]+(a,b)}{[a,b] \cdot (a,b)}$?

Comment: Please don't delete questions after someone has given an answer. It is unfair to those who have worked on your question and it looks as if you are  trying to hide the fact that you have asked the question.

Comment: Note that [a,b](a,b)=ab

Answer (score 1):

Given $(c,d)=1$ and $g$, we get the pair $(a,b)=(gc,gd)$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12
&=\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1{(a,b)}+\frac1{[a,b]}\\
&=\frac1{gc}+\frac1{gd}+\frac1g+\frac1{gcd}\\
&=\frac1g\left(1+\frac1c\right)\left(1+\frac1d\right)
\end{align}
$$
That is
$$
g=2\left(1+\frac1c\right)\left(1+\frac1d\right)
$$
Here are all the possibilities
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
c&d&g&(gc,gd)\\\hline
1&1&8&(8,8)\\
1&2&6&(6,12)\\
1&4&5&(5,20)\\
2&3&4&(8,12)\\
3&8&3&(9,24)\\
4&5&3&(12,15)
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $gcd(a,b)=d$.
Thus, $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\geq\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}$$ it's
$$\frac{1}{a_1d}+\frac{1}{b_1d}\geq\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{da_1b_1}$$ or
$$(a_1-1)(b_1-1)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Now, let $a\geq b$.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}\leq2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right)\leq\frac{4}{b},$$
which gives $b\leq8$, which says $d\leq8$.

Also, $$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{(a,b)}+\frac{1}{[a,b]}$$ it's
 $$\frac{1}{a_1d}+\frac{1}{b_1d}+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{da_1b_1}=\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$2(1+a_1)(1+b_1)=a_1b_1d,$$ which gives $d>2$.

Now, it remains a work with last equation for $3\leq d\leq8,$ which gives all solutions.

Can you end it now?